# Accesing dta inside array/list

Tags: python, arrays

Sourde Data:

```
List = [
{'S': 'DOGEBUSD', 'P': '0.29123000', 'F': '2021-08-26 00:06:24'}, 
{'S': 'DOGEBUSD', 'P': '0.29121000', 'F': '2021-08-26 00:06:30'}
]
```

Total Count: 370

I need to access the data like:

```
print (P[0])
>> 0.29123000
```

but I'm completely tied up, I tried with the cursor, using "split", looking and rewiring but I can't find the key.

Python v3
Ubuntu

Comment: print (List[0]['P'])  0.28990000  i feel quite stupid. Thank you very much. :big hug:

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
List[0]['P']
```

if you want all `'P'` try this:

```
List = [
{'S': 'DOGEBUSD', 'P': '0.29123000', 'F': '2021-08-26 00:06:24'}, 
{'S': 'DOGEBUSD', 'P': '0.29121000', 'F': '2021-08-26 00:06:30'}
]

print([item['P'] for item in List])
# ['0.29123000', '0.29121000']
```

Comment: 0.29141000 <-- thank you user1740577 & python_user 7
    0.29149000 <-- thank you user1740577 & python_user 7
    0.29175000 <-- thank you user1740577 & python_user 7
    0.29123000 <-- thank you user1740577 & python_user 7
    0.29123000 <-- thank you user1740577 & python_user 7

    Total Count: 370  ( in my screen its ok, one price per line)  Thank you.